# Create a zip with ZipArchive and include the real files of symbolic links

Tags: php, composer-php, zip, php-ziparchive

We do a folder structure like this

```
/
/index.html
/css
/css/custom.css
/css/vendor/main.css <-- this is a working symbolic like
```

Now we wan't to pack the whole folder in a zip. So far it works, but it doesn't handle the symlinks correct. On Some system it just ignores them, on other system it put the absolute path in it. How can we force to follow the symlink and copy the real file in the "symlinked structure".

```
public static function zip_files(Event $event, $source, $destination)
{
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($destination, \ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) {
        $source = realpath($source);
        if (is_dir($source)) {
            $iterator = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source);
            $iterator->setFlags(\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
            $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $file = realpath($file);
                if (is_dir($file)) {
                    $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '', $file . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
                } elseif (is_file($file)) {
                    $zip->addFile($file, str_replace($source . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '', $file));
                }
            }
        } elseif (is_file($source)) {
            $zip->addFile($source, basename($source));
        }
    }
    $event->getIO()->write(sprintf('<info>Created/Updated "%s" in "%s"<info>', $source, $destination));
    return $zip->close();
}
```

Foreach where we call it.

```
    foreach ($archives as $OutputZipName => $RelativeFolderToBeZipped) {


        $source = realpath($RelativeFolderToBeZipped);
        $fileName = $OutputZipName . '.zip';

        $destination = realpath($outputFolder['dir']) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

        self::zip_files($event, $source, $destination);
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Fabrizo_Cocco, You have already have another function and class coming with php. I think that can be more easy than the ziparchive for your problem,exemple you can use Phar class than zip is the same, yeah it's not young but i think he can resolve your problem

Comment: Why is this tagged with Composer? Is this in any way related to Composer?